Combining lines that are seperated by a small gap
I am having issues trying to figure out how to mass combine line segments that are seperated by a small gap. They have the same info in the attributes with one exception. I read something about an unsplit tool but I cannot seem to find this. I am new to QGIS.
How can I do this?



Look at the v.clean or snap tools to get rid of the gaps by snapping their ends together..  Then run a dissolve based on the attributes to put the line segments together.

Can you add a screenshot showing some of the data? Do you have one or two layers?

Yes, I have added pictures of the lines that I would like to combine and the attribute table. I am also wondering if maybe there is a way that I can combine the ones that are duplicates in the attribute table and get it to work that way. With the snap tools wouldn't I have to go into each and every one in order to fix it or could I do it in large chunks? It is a lot of data to sift through in order to one by one,
